# SharePoint List JSON formatting (make a text look like a Choice Pill)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

1. Is it possible to make a number column appear like a Choice pill? Instead of the value being in a rectangle box, it would display with rounded corners.

Instead of this:

[image]

Get the numbers into something like this:

[image]

2. How can I get the text to display vertically centered in the box?  It appears to be top justified.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
            ""
          ]
        },
        "",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": ">=",
              "operands": [
                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                0.1
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-BlackText",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "&&",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": ">=",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                        0.05
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "<=",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                        0.1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCyan sp-css-borderColor-CyanFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "&&",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": ">=",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "<=",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                            0.05
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgSage sp-css-borderColor-SageFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "&&",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": ">=",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                -0.05
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "operator": "<=",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                0
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgPeach sp-css-borderColor-PeachFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "&&",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": ">=",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                    -0.05
                                  ]
                                },
                                {
                                  "operator": "<=",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                    -0.1
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-color-BlackText",
                            {
                              "operator": ":",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": ">=",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                    -0.1
                                  ]
                                },
                                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-borderColor-CoralFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                                ""
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A.displayValue]"
}
```

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharePoint column formatting JSON for your number type column like this:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                ""
              ]
            },
            "",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": ">=",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                    0.1
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-BlackText",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "&&",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": ">=",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                            0.05
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "<=",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                            0.1
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCyan sp-css-borderColor-CyanFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "&&",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": ">=",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "operator": "<=",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                0.05
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgSage sp-css-borderColor-SageFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "&&",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": ">=",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                    -0.05
                                  ]
                                },
                                {
                                  "operator": "<=",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                    0
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgPeach sp-css-borderColor-PeachFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                            {
                              "operator": ":",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": "&&",
                                  "operands": [
                                    {
                                      "operator": ">=",
                                      "operands": [
                                        "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                        -0.05
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "operator": "<=",
                                      "operands": [
                                        "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                        -0.1
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                },
                                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-color-BlackText",
                                {
                                  "operator": ":",
                                  "operands": [
                                    {
                                      "operator": ">=",
                                      "operands": [
                                        "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A]",
                                        -0.1
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-borderColor-CoralFont sp-css-color-BlackText",
                                    ""
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "[$RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A.displayValue]"
    }
  ],
  "templateId": "BgColorChoicePill"
}
```

Where `RevenueYTD_x0028_Current_x002f_A` is the internal name of your number column. You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint list column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)